# Documenting methods in top-level namespace with YARD

Tags: ruby, methods, yard

I documented some Ruby code using YARD and I am having trouble getting the YARD
documentation I created for some methods in top-level name space to show up in
yardoc's HTML output.

My documentation looks essentially the same as the YARD gem's own in
lib/yard/globals.rb,  with the addition of an `@api` tag. I did try removing it,
and ran `yardoc` without the `--api` parameter but that didn't help matters.

This is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# @group PIP Negotiation: Backend and helper methods
#
# Deserializes a topology graph in YAML format into the database.
#
# @api pip-negotiate
# @param [String] graph A FleRD graph in YAML format
# @return [Boolean] status True if graph was deserialized successfully, False otherwise.
# @return [Integer] gl_id The database ID of the deserialized GraphLabel (nil if deserialization failed).
# @return [Array] output Standard output channel of flerd-deserialize.rb(1)
# @return [Array] output Standard error channel of flerd-deserialize.rb(1)

def insert_graph(graph)
  return [ true, 1, ["1"], [""] ]  # Not the actual method body.
end

# @endgroup
```

When I run `yardoc` to generate the HTML documentation everything looks fine
at first:

```
% yardoc -o pip-negotiate --api pip-negotiate '**/*.rb'                  
Files:           1
Modules:         0 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:         0 (    0 undocumented)
Constants:       0 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:         1 (    0 undocumented)
 100.00% documented
%
```

The generated HTML does not contain any of my documentation though. All it
contains is a list of methods with the `pip-negotiate` API tag. You can see for
yourself here:

http://btw23.de/tmp/pip-negotiate/api/method_list.html

What I expected instead was something more like YARD's own documentation on
top-level methods:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/toplevel

Is there perhaps any special magic I am missing in my `yardoc` invocation?

My yardoc version is 0.8.6.2, running on Ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Rather than link your code, could you please paste in just enough to the question replicate the problem you are facing? It would improve the question, and keep it relevant once you fix your project code due to the answer. As a side effect that would allow you to have the second link.

Comment: Right, I should have thought of that (fixed). Thanks!

Comment: I copied your example and found that `yardoc -o pip-negotiate **/*.rb` produced something that looked correct. Adding `--api` or `--api pip-negotiate` seemed to break it again, but I do not yet understand or explain why. `yard 0.8.7.2`

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Information necessary to understand the problem needs to be _in the question itself_. Links to the output can rot and break, making it difficult to understand for others trying to help or those searching in the future for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The presence or absence of `--api` doesn't seem to make a difference. Both
with and without the equals sign the `--api` option causes none of the method
documentation to show up. It does work in other cases, no matter the
equals sign; I've been using it a lot to compartmentalize documentation on a
bunch of instance methods that are not in top-level namespace. I believe I
have found the reason now.

Apparently the `@api` tag is somewhat namespace sensitive, and in a peculiar
way. Consider this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# @api pip-negotiate

class Foo

# Deserializes a topology graph in YAML format into the database.
#
# @param [String] graph A FleRD graph in YAML format
# @return [Boolean] status True if graph was deserialized successfully, False otherwise.
# @return [Integer] gl_id The database of the deserialized GraphLabel (nil if deserialization failed).
# @return [Array] output Standard output of flerd-deserialize.rb(1)

def insert_graph(graph)
  return true, 1, ["1"], [""]  # Not the actual method body.
end

end
```

With either of these two `yardoc` invocations it will render the
method documentation for `insert_graph()` fine:

```
% yardoc -o pip-negotiate --api=pip-negotiate '**/*.rb'
% yardoc -o pip-negotiate --api pip-negotiate '**/*.rb'
```

But if we move the `@api` tag down to the method it will break things:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Foo

# Deserializes a topology graph in YAML format into the database.
#
# @param [String] graph A FleRD graph in YAML format
# @return [Boolean] status True if graph was deserialized successfully, False otherwise.
# @return [Integer] gl_id The database of the deserialized GraphLabel (nil if deserialization failed).
# @return [Array] output Standard output of flerd-deserialize.rb(1)
# @api pip-negotiate

def insert_graph(graph)
  return true, 1, ["1"], [""]  # Not the actual method body.
end

end
```

No matter the `yardoc` invocation, the method documentation is ignored, but the
method gets listed. My hypothesis, since I don't have the spare cycles to
verify it from YARD's source, is that there needs to be an unbroken chain of
`@api` tags from the outermost taggable namespace, which would be the Foo class
in this example. And so far I haven't found a way to tag the top-level namespace,
helpful though that would be.

That being said, the comment on `--api` breaking things got me on the right
track: While the method documentation still doesn't show up in the method
list if I omit the `--api` parameter, it does show up in the class list of all
places (under "Top Level Namespace"). That's why it eluded me the first time I
tried omitting the `--api` parameter.

I'll try to work with the YARD formatter to keep the method list from being displayed, so it
doesn't confuse my users as it confused me, and try to compartmentalize my
documentation/refactor my code such that I don't require multiple `@api` tags in
any given file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax appears to be:

```
yardoc -o pip-negotiate --api=pip-negotiate '**/*.rb'
```

The equals sign is apparently needed for the `--api` option to work correctly. I suspect otherwise the name `pip-negotiate` was being used as an input file name to parse for documentation.